# Php fatal error. How to include a class into index.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having problem with my site.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'innovation_ruby_util' not found in D:\inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\innovation\index.php on line 7
```

Please help me with adding classes in the code below

```
<?php
/**
* Innovation created by ThemeRuby
* This file display home layout
*/
//get home options

$ruby_options['page_layout'] = innovation_ruby_util::get_theme_option( 'home_layout' );
$ruby_options['sidebar_name'] = innovation_ruby_util::get_theme_option( 'home_sidebar' );
$ruby_options['sidebar_position'] = innovation_ruby_util::get_theme_option( 'home_sidebar_position' );

$ruby_options['big_first'] = innovation_ruby_util::get_theme_option( 'big_post_first' );

if ( 'default' == $ruby_options['sidebar_position'] ) {
    $ruby_options['sidebar_position'] = innovation_ruby_util::get_theme_option( 'site_sidebar_position' );
}

//render featured area
get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'featured' );

//render home columns
get_template_part('templates/section','columns');

//render layout
innovation_ruby_blog_layout::render( $ruby_options );
```

Comment: You need [**`require_once`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php). Something like `require_once(path-to-class-file);`

Comment: I don't know php, can you please tell me where to add this code in my index.php file

Comment: do you need to use in all pages?

Comment: I am having problem with index.php theme file

Answer (score 0):

I can show you core PHP way.

```
<?php
/**
 * Innovation created by ThemeRuby
 * This file display home layout
 */
//get home options

require_once("<path-to-class-file>");

$ruby_options['page_layout'] = innovation_ruby_util::get_theme_option( 'home_layout' );
$ruby_options['sidebar_name'] = innovation_ruby_util::get_theme_option( 'home_sidebar' );
.
.
.
```

Comment: I have added this code

<?php
/**
 * Innovation created by ThemeRuby
 * This file display home layout
 */
//get home options
require_once("innovation_ruby_util");

Now its showing 

PHP Warning:  require_once(innovation_ruby_util): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\inetpub\vhosts\blacklisthackers.com\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\innovation\index.php on line 7

Please tell me the solution i am unable to resolve this issue :(
Can you please tell me where i have to create innovation_ruby_util
class??

Comment: @blacklisthackers: based upon the warning, I guess, you need to create `innovation_ruby_util` class at root directory of the project.